# Can custom account lockout per user work for ASP.NET, Identidy, Oauth 2.0 and WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

We need to have different account lockout criteria for entering an invalid username/password based on the type of user.  Internal users would get locked out after 5 failures and outside users would get locked out after 3 failures.

Number of failed username/password attempts is used for simplicity. Our criteria is more complicated.

This uses username/password and not any type of Windows domain based security.

Scenario:

- A WPF application
- ASP.NET MVC5 (not core) WebAPI
- ASP.NET Identity 2.x, Oauth 2.0 using Entity Framework 6 connected to SQL Server 2012.
- Visual Studio 2015, C#, .NET 4.6.x

We have classes derived from UserManager, UserStore, SignInManager and OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.

Where in one of the ASP.NET identity classes should this logic go?

There are many web pages around this but they are for HTML pages in a MVC project and not for WebAPI.  For example: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/

Does a process flow diagram for ASP.NET identity behind WebAPI exist?

Comment: We've tried setting IsLockoutEnabled in the AspNetUsers table entry as well as UserManager settings (DefauitAccountLockoutTimeSpan, MaxFailedAccessAttemtpsBeforeLockout, and UserLockoutEnabledbyDefault True).

Comment: Does the same technique as in article you link not work in WebAPI?

Comment: Our criteria for lockout is more complicated and based on different classes of user.